# Issues getting customer data

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, customer-group

I am trying to access the logged in customer's data from an observer and a helper

With the following code

```
 var_dump($customer = Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer()->getData());
```

I get the following result

```
array(1) { ["website_id"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Which doesn't give me information like group id or customer id.

Could anyone help

Answer (score 2):

Try using the customer session.

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
```

This will get you the current logged in customer session. From this you can simply load the customer data from the objects attached.

```
$customer = $session->getCustomer();
```

Comment: I have tried

$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$customer = $session->getCustomer();
var_dump($customer->getData());

And I still get array(1) { ["website_id"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: @Goose84 and you customer is actually logged in?

Comment: Yep definitely logged in as I can now see the account dashboard

Comment: @Goose84 at what point do you call this code? What event is it

Comment: The event is controller_action_predispatch_cms_page_view and I have my own custom observer with a custom method

Comment: It could be that this event is too early

Answer (score 0):

You can customer data using  `Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer()` code whenever customer is `loggedin at frontend` otherwise you `cannot  get customer data` .

see function:

```
public function getCustomer()
{
    if (empty($this->_customer)) {
        $this->_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    }
    return $this->_customer;
}
```

Comment: If i do `$customer =  mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer();  var_dump($customer->getId());`

It returns null

Comment: yes..if customer is not loggedin.